How can rotate along the vertical axis of the window
I want to use the middle mouse button to rotate and check the model I have made
When I drag the mouse from left to right, I find that it rotates along the z-axis of the global coordinate system
How can I set it to rotate along the vertical axis of the window
The rotation axis I want is shown in the picture
Please note that I do not want to rotate the object, but rather to rotate the view


AFAIK, you cannot do that, but if you can it’s in Preferences -> Navigation.

Set your transform orientation to View. The default hotkey for the Orientation menu is ",". Be aware that the "Z" axis in view mode is moving perpendicular to your screen. "Up" (toward the top of your screen) is the Y axis in View mode.



This setting can indeed rotate a single object along the axis I have drawn, But what I actually want to rotate is the entire scene, not just one object

then you just select all the objects in the scene. Transform orientation doesn't limit the number of objects you can transform.

But this will change the coordinate values of the object's vertices, and I don't want this to happen

Do you have rotate around selection, in your preferences? It's under Navigation pretty sure.
